# Use decorator function to compare execution times

Tags: python, performance, decorator

After coming across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/how-to-make-a-chain-of-function-decorators) excellent explanation about decorators, I realized decorators can be quite useful to display function execution times. My ultimate goal is to create a function

```
compare_functions(f1, f2)
```

that compares the execution times of two functions f1 and f2. As a start I designed this decorator:

```
def clean_exec_time(fnc):
    def wrapper(*args):
        t0 = time.perf_counter()
        fnc(*args)
        t1 = time.perf_counter()
        print(t1-t0)
return wrapper
```

Which can be used perfectly in this way:

```
@clean_exec_time
def print_msg(msg):
    print(msg)
```

Such that

```
print_msg('Hi') 
# outputs:
# Hi
# 3.0109e-05
```

That's great. It get's tricky (for me) when I try to work my way to the ultimate goal.

```
@clean_exec_time
def compare_functions(f1, f2): 
    a = 2 #not sure what to put here
```

Now I see the following:

```
compare_functions(print_msg('Hi'), print_msg('See ya'))
# outputs
# Hi
# 3.0793e-05
# See ya
# 1.1291e-05
# 6.5010e-05
```

I have a few questions:

1. Why are 2 execution times printed after 'See ya'?
2. What do I need to modify in order to see a value c printed that denotes the number of times f1 is faster/slower than f2.
3. It feels strange not to put anything meaningful in my function compare_functions. Is there an elegant way to cope with this?

Comment: The last time is the execution time of the compare_functions itself, because it is also decorated for time measurement

Comment: You can just measure and compare the times in `compare_functions`, the decorator won't help you there. Though in this case you have to use functions or lambda as arguments to be able to execute them inside your compare function.

Comment: Thanks @Alex, did not know that.

Comment: I suppose you're right @MrBeanBremen, maybe I got caught up in this decorator functionality too much.

Comment: But how would you work around the decorator? I guess the point is I find it hard to pass a function including arguments as a function.

Comment: I would just suggest to use standard timeit function. However, performance measurement is always tricky.

Comment: @Christov - look up lambda functions, this is what you need to pass functions with arguments

Comment: Yes, found -and applied- it! Not perfect in the sense that the original function name is lost, but it indeed suits the purpose.

Comment: I added a couple of other possibilities in the answer - none very nice, but you may have a look...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed, one possibility is to use lambdas as arguments:

```
def compare_time(f1, f2):
    t0 = time.perf_counter()
    f1()
    t1 = time.perf_counter()
    f2()
    t2 = time.perf_counter()
    print(f"Time diff is {(t1 - t0) - (t2 - t1)} s")

compare_time(lambda: print_msg('Hi'), lambda: print_msg('See ya'))
```

This gives:

```
Hi
See ya
Time diff is 1.9200000000010875e-05 s
```

Unfortunately, lambda functions do not have information about the called function.
If you need this, here is a hacky solution, that takes the strings of the functions calls:

```
def compare_time1(f1, f2):
    t0 = time.perf_counter()
    eval(f1)
    t1 = time.perf_counter()
    eval(f2)
    t2 = time.perf_counter()
    print(f"Time diff between {f1} and {f2} is {(t1 - t0) - (t2 - t1)} s")

compare_time1("print_msg('Hi')", "print_msg('See ya')")
```

This gives:

```
Hi
See ya
Time diff between print_msg('Hi') and print_msg('See ya') is 3.0000000000002247e-05 s
```

Another possibility is to separate function names and arguments - not so hacky, but also not very convenient:

```
def compare_time2(f1, args1, f2, args2):
    t0 = time.perf_counter()
    f1(*args1)
    t1 = time.perf_counter()
    f2(*args2)
    t2 = time.perf_counter()
    print(f"Time diff between {f1.__name__}({str(args1)[1:-1]}) and"
          f" {f2.__name__}({str(args2)[1:-1]}) is {(t1 - t0) - (t2 - t1)} s")

compare_time2(print_msg, ['Hi'], print_msg, ['See ya'])
```

This gives:

```
Hi
See ya
Time diff between print_msg('Hi') and print_msg('See ya') is 8.000000000091267e-07 s
```

Answer (score 1):

`compare_functions` is the wrong function to decorate, because you want to time each of the functions being *passed* to `compare_functions`, not `compare_functions` itself.

I find it more useful to time code with a context manager.

```
import time
import contextlib


class TimeResult:
    def __init__(self):
        self._start = None
        self._stop = None

    def start(self):
        self._start = time.perf_counter()

    def stop(self):
        self._stop = time.perf_counter()

    @property
    def result(self):
        if self._start is None or self._stop is None:
            return None
        return self._stop - self._start
```

This is a simple class whose `result` property is `None` until after you've called both its `start` and `stop` methods (preferably in that order)

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
def timeit():
    t = TimeResult()
    t.start()
    yield t
    t.stop()
```

This creates a context manager that yields a `TimeResult` object whose `start` and `stop` methods are called at on entry to and on exit from a `with` statement, respectively.

```
def compare_functions(f1, f2): 
    with timeit() as t1:
        f1()

    print(f'Function 1 took {t1.result} seconds')

    with timeit() as t2:
        f2()

    print(f'Function 2 took {t2.result} seconds')
```

`compare_functions` takes two functions to call, and times each of them the the `timeit` context manager. As each function completes, the elapsed time is reported.

Then

```
def print_msg(msg):
    print(msg)

compare_functions(lambda: print_msg("hi"), lambda: print_msg("see ya"))
```

takes two functions to call and time.

Alternatively, you can pass the functions to time and the arguments separately, and let `compare_functions` combine them.

```
def compare_functions(f_and_args_1, f_and_args_2):
    f1, *args1 = f_and_args1
    f2, *args2 = f_and_args2

    with timeit() as t1:
        f1(*args1)

    print(f'{f1.__name__} took {t1.result} seconds')

    with timeit() as t2:
        f2(*args2)

    print(f'{f2.__name__} took {t2.result} seconds')



compare_functions((print_msg, "hi"), (print_msg, "see ya"))
```

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, this is the what I've done (*without decorators*).

```
def compare_functions(f1, f2, reps=1):
    text_trap = io.StringIO()    # 
    sys.stdout = text_trap       # These two lines avoid print statements 
    fnc1 = get_func(f1)
    fnc2 = get_func(f2)
    c1 = get_exec_time(fnc1, reps)
    c2 = get_exec_time(fnc2, reps)
    sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__   # turn print statement back on
    if c1 > c2:
        print('Function {0} is {1:.2f} times faster than function {2}'.format(1, c1/c2, 2))
    if c2 > c1:
        print('Function {0} is {1:.2f} times faster than function {2}'.format(2, c2/c1, 1))
```

Where

```
def get_func(fnc):
    if not callable(fnc):
        return lambda: fnc
    else:
        return fnc

def get_system_speed():           #used as benchmark
    t0 = time.perf_counter()
    do_calc()                     #arbritrary function
    return time.perf_counter()-t0

def get_exec_time(fnc, reps=1):
    ex_times = []
    for i in range(reps):
        c = get_system_speed()
        t0 = time.perf_counter()
        fnc()
        ex_times.append((time.perf_counter()-t0)/c)
return np.average(ex_times)
```

This allows me to compare the execution times of two (lambda) functions, by executing each function *reps* times and benchmarking each run to the system speed at that moment. For example, using the print_msg function as above:

```
compare_functions(lambda: print_msg('hi'), lambda: print_msg('hi'), reps=10000)
# outputs
# Function 2 is 1.00 times faster than function 1
```

Thanks for the help and suggestions!